# Will "copy elision" and "named return value optimization (NRVO)" work in a recursive function?

Tags: c++, c++17

In C++, compilers are specifically allowed to perform "copy elision," and more specifically "named return value optimization," (NRVO) such that a function-local variable isn't even `move()`'d to a variable in the caller's stack frame, but is in fact *itself* in the caller's stack frame.

Can this be assumed to work with recursive functions?  Or should I have the caller manually pass in the storage?

```
vector<MyClass*> MyClass::GetHeirarchy() {
    vector<MyClass*> apclass;

    if ( pclassParent )
        apclass = pclassParent->GetHeirarchy();

    apclass.push_back( this );
    return apclass;    
}
```

Here's the same function written without assuming NRVO.  Oddly, it seems shorter and simpler.

```
void MyClass::GetHeirarchy( vector<MyClass*>* papclass ) {

    if ( pclassParent )
        pclassParent->GetHeirarchy( papclass );

    apclass->push_back( this );
}
```

Comment: What good would NVRO be if you then still move assign the return value to a local variable?

Comment: In any case it would be preferable to use iteration instead of recursion, so you don't have to rely on the compiler figuring out that the recursive calls can be optimized away. You don't want to run into stack overflows.

Comment: A recursive call is no different from a regular function call - each call has its own stack frame, so there's no reason why NVRO shouldn't work in this case.  But why `vector<MyClass*>` instead of `vector<MyClass>`?  Or perhaps `vector<std::unique_ptr <MyClass>>` if polymorphism, is involved?  And, as you can see, you don't need `class` in there - the compiler already knows that (or, if it doesn't, forward declare `MyClass` somewhere first).

Comment: `class MyClass` should just be `MyClass`. The `class` prefix implies that the compiler will not complain if `MyClass` isn't declared and will instead consider it a forward-declaration. This hides mistakes such as typos and may result in weird error messages later, e.g. when you notice that it didn't declare the class in the scope you expected. (Consider whether it is going to be declared as a nested class or at the namespace scope or maybe the block scope?)

Comment: Note that this doesn't need recursion; it can just be unrolled into a `while` loop.

Comment: *What good would NVRO be if you then still move assign the return value to a local variable?* -- doesn't NVRO elide the move assign, and simply have the function-scoped variable in fact live in the caller's stack frame?

Comment: *each call has its own stack frame, so there's no reason why NVRO shouldn't work in this case* -- that's not obvious, which is why I'm asking.  In traditional NVRO the function-scoped variable that is returned simply isn't in the function at all, but rather in the caller's frame, right?  And yet, the variable in this case would have to be actually in the caller's caller's frame... or caller's caller's caller's frame.

Comment: *But why vector<MyClass*> instead of vector<MyClass>?* -- does the answer to my query vary depending on what this "why" is?  Maybe I'm missing something but I don't see how it matters what the "why" is, or what the vector is?

Comment: *class MyClass should just be MyClass* -- many thanks, a cut-and-paste error I have now corrected.

Comment: *Note that this doesn't need recursion; it can just be unrolled into a while loop. * -- First, it's a constructed example.  If it didn't have recursion, I wouldn't be able to ask my question, therefore it MUST have recursion.  Second, how WOULD you create this in a while loop?  Note that `this` is last in the vector.

Comment: apologies, I now understand elision only works for the initialization of an object, not for assignment, though it isn't clear to me why it wasn't done for assignments as well.

Comment: It’s ‘hierarchy’.

Comment: Feel free to correct it.

Comment: @SwissFrank As a loop, you would build the vector backwards then reverse it (`for (MyClass* ptr = this; ptr; ptr = ptr->pclassParent) apclass.push_back(ptr); std::ranges::reverse(apclass); return apclass;`). A similar thing is done in the recursive case, except the reversed array of pointers is in stack frames.

Comment: Artyer obviously.  But @Thomas 's assertion isn't that it can be unrolled into a while loop plus a call to reverse it.  Thomas says "it can just be unrolled into a while loop."

Comment: @SwissFrank You're right, I missed that, you need to reverse it at the end. I never did say that the question was invalid; it's a fine question :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no elision here:

> ```
> apclass = pclassParent->GetHeirarchy();
> ```

This is assignment. It is *always* assignment. Elision is about the *initialization* of an object. `apclass` is already initialized at this point, so this just assigns to an existing object.

If you want elision to be possible within a recursive call, then you need to either return `GetHeirarchy` directly or use its return value to initialize a local that you then return with modifications.

But in general, the kind of algorithm you're implementing (where you're conceptually creating a single object through recursive manipulation of said object) is not something where elision will be generally helpful. The final object can be elided, but the various steps that manipulate the object should be done as clear object manipulation:

```
void MyClass::GetHeirarchyRec( vector<MyClass*>& apclass ) {

    if ( pclassParent )
        pclassParent->GetHeirarchyRec( apclass );

    apclass.push_back( this );
}

void MyClass::GetHeirarchy()
{
    vector<MyClass*> ret;
    GetHierarchyRec(ret);
    return ret;
}
```

This way, the user interface of just receiving an array is preserved.

Comment: Thanks.  I didn't realize elision only occurs for initialization and not assignment.  What do you mean by "return GetHeirarchy directly"?  Also curious why you changed my example from pointers to references?

Comment: @SwissFrank: Because pointers can be null easily; it's a lot harder for references to be null. An interface that takes a pointer looks suspiciously like an interface where it is OK to *pass* null. Since it's very much not OK to do that, you should take a reference.